# can't pass block to Kernel sub method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run a ruby one-liner in bash, and this is what happens:

```
~$ echo a$'\n'b$'\n'c | ruby -pe 'sub(/./,"x")'
x
x
x
~$ echo a$'\n'b$'\n'c | ruby -pe '$_.sub!(/./){"x"}'
x
x
x
~$ echo a$'\n'b$'\n'c | ruby -pe 'sub(/./){"x"}'
-e:1:in `sub': wrong number of arguments (1 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
        from -e:1:in `sub'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Why doesn't command #3 work exactly like command #2?

(This is ruby 1.9.2.  The echo statement is there only to provide three lines of input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was a [bug in 1.9.2](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7157). It was [fixed for 2.0.0](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/9e02550b21e2fa73049284fa8f0b6c5d8a2d5394) (and [backported to 1.9.3](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/259d9dbc20f7841c11460bf0ae0530ba121b4799)). The fix is simply to upgrade to a more recent version of Ruby.

You should probably upgrade if you can anyway, since [support for 1.9.2 has just ended](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/).

Comment: d'oh!
thanks.  I don't own the server I'm on, so I'll have to twist some arms :|